# Cannot see offsets committed to __consumer_offsets topic in Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a Spark Streaming Scala application that reads data from a Kafka topic and places it on HDFS. I want the app to store offsets of read messages to *__consumer_offsets* topic in order to start reading from it in case of the app's failure. The app runs fine (I can see the data on HDFS), but I cannot see its commits to *__consumer_offsets*.

Here is my KafkaParams:

```
val kafkaParams = Map(
      "metadata.broker.list" -> "xx.xxx.x.xx:6667",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> "true",
      "group.id" -> "reading_telemetry",
      "offsets.storage" -> "kafka"
    )
```

The command I use to get committed offsets from __consumer_offsets is the following:

```
$ /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --consumer.config /tmp/consumer.config   --zookeeper xx.xxx.x.xx:2181   --topic __consumer_offsets --from-beginning --formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter"
```

I get some info on committed offsets of the form

> [test1,test,0]::[OffsetMetadata[55,NO_METADATA],CommitTime
>   1539603328309,ExpirationTime 6723603328309]

But I don't see any commits for the "reading_telemetry" group ID. Any idea, why?

My environment:

Kafka: 1.0.1
Spark: 2.3.1
Scala: 2.11.8

Answer (score 1):

Use kafka-consumer-groups.sh script as given below :

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --bootstrap-server <BootStrapServerIP:port> --describe --group telemetryGroup
```

It will return information in below format :

```
GROUP                  TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG       OWNER
telemetryGroup        test-topic      0          15              15              0         telemetryGroup-1/127.0.0.1
telemetryGroup        test-topic      1          14              15              1         telemetryGroup-2_/127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly read from the `__consumer_offsets` topic. This is an internal topic and you should instead use tools to retrieve committed offsets.

The easiest is to run the `kafka-consumer-groups` tool:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh \
    --bootstrap-server [BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS] \
    --describe \
    --group reading_telemetry
```

The column `CURRENT-OFFSET` contains the committed offset.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just tried - got this result:


Error: Consumer group 'reading_telemetry' does not exist.


This is strange, since I specified the group ID in the KafkaParams object. Any idea where to go from here?

Comment: In Kafka 1.0, by default, committed offsets are only retained 24hours (`offsets.retention.minutes`). Could it be that your application has not committed within this time frame? If not, then I'm afraid, we'd need consumer logs to identify the cause.